# How to read Metadata?

Tags: xamarin.ios, branch.io

I use branch.IO lib for xamarin.Ios and want to read a metadata from BranchUniversalObject. However public field metadata is empty. I see valid data in private field _customMetadata.

```
public void InitSessionComplete(BranchUniversalObject buo, BranchLinkProperties blp)
{
    Log("Branch parameters received:");
    var metadata = buo.metadata.Metadata;
    foreach (var pair in metadata)
    {
        Log($"   {pair.Key} : {pair.Value}");
    }
    Resolver.Instance.Resolve<IEnumerable<IInstallParametersListener>>()
        .ForEach(listener => listener.OnParametersReceived(metadata));
}
```

[image]

In xamarin.Droid  data is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackie from Branch here.

First, I'd recommend checking to ensure that you do the following:

- Call BranchiOS init in FinishedLaunching with the correct Branch key
- Call BranchiOS OpenUrl in OpenUrl and ContinueUserActivity in ContinueUserActivity
  link created on the same Branch key as the SDK is initialized.

Once the above checks out, please follow the instruction [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/xamarin/#read-deep-link) in order to configure your setup for reading link data properly. You can learn more about the Xamarin integration process on our docs: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/xamarin/#integrate-branch

If you need further help, please feel free to reach out to us directly at integrations@branch.io